# using touchslider.com to pass option to open on slide 2

Tags: jquery, touch, slide

I am using touchslider.com and have a question about implementing a start slide

Currently it always starts on slide 1 but there are sometimes where I would like it to start on slide 2.

the html would be something like

```
<div class="touchslider">
<div class="touchslider-viewport" style="width:500px;overflow:hidden"><div>
    <div class="touchslider-item">page1</div>
    <div class="touchslider-item">page2</div>
    ...
</div></div>

<div>
    <span class="touchslider-nav-item touchslider-nav-item-current">1</span>
    <span class="touchslider-nav-item">2</span>

</div>
</div>
```

this is then started by

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
 jQuery(".touchslider").touchSlider({/*options*/});
});
</script>
```

and the JavaScript is

http://touchslider.com/jquery.touchslider.js

I want to pass an option like startSlide but this is not a current option.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do this

in the main page

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
 jQuery(".touchslider").touchSlider({ startSlide:2}); 
});
</script>
```

and then added this to the JS

in the options added

startSlide:1

then near where the default next button is

```
if ( options.startSlide > 1  ) {
        startSlide(options.startSlide);
}
```

and then added this function

```
function startSlide(number, complete) {
        switching.to(ret.current + number-1, { dirX: + number-1, complete: complete });
}
```